# CSS cross-browser issue with DIV top property

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

There is one issue that drives me nuts for several days. I created a theme for Wordpress especially CSS http://fabienmischler.com/. The problem is the DIV line on the right side is only aligned within Chrome Mac-version and Safari. All other Browser (INCLUDING CHROME Win-version) render it differently. The same happens with the Contact form on the right (that is a modified plugin from slick-form). Is there any elegant way to fix this issue or do I need to use CSS hacks? and if yes how for Chrome Windows version?

The container is absolute, the DIV (with the line) too.

Here is the DIV

```
#hr-title {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 100px;
width: 14%;
height: 1px;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: black; }
```

This DIV is part of the Container-Div (standard in Wordpress):

```
div#container {
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
height: 100%;
right: 0;
top: 0; }
```

All this is packed in the standard stylesheet (style.css) from Wordpress.

I CSS reset the sheet according to Eric Meyer http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking questions here, please include the relevant code in the question. You probably won't get many answers if all you've given us is a link to your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the rendering of the text on the different browser, especially the `line-height` and `vertical-alignment` on texts. They are never identical ...

A possible solution would be to not use the `underlined text decoration` for your line under title but to draw it as a separate element using the same `top` position as your other line. This way, it will always be correctly aligned on each browser.

Here is some sample CSS code to achieve it:

```
h1 { float: right; text-decoration: none; }
h1:before { content: " "; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 1px; top: 101px; background: #000; }
```

**Update**

Another solution would be to absolute position the line relative to the title. Setting the line relative to the title to a top of `16px` aligns equally with the outer line which is positioned on `96px`

```
#hr-title { top: 96px; }
h1.entry-title { float: right; position: relative; text-decoration: none; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h1:before { background: #000; width: 100%; height: 1px; top: 16px; position: absolute; content: " "; }
```

Comment: Hi Mike,thanks a lot for your answer, that helped already. unfortunately it is still not properly rendered and my CSS hacks do not work anymore... I dont know why.

Comment: I figured out it did not, as it created a larger window - unfortunately on the left side. Because the "width: 100%;" is the whole container which was added to the right. But thanks for your help. maybe you have another idea?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution. Tested it on FF & Chrome and renders correctly.